# Unable to stop Process "idleassetsd" from consuming infinite bandwidth on MacOS Ventura & Sonoma

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, activity-monitor

Unable to stop the process "idleassetsd" to consume internet bandwidth, While force quitting the process it starts consuming the bandwidth again, Nothing is working to stop it Observed under macOS (Ventura & Sonoma)

Sync to iCloud is turned off, No developer software is installed. Also the auto software update for Mac is Disabled.

Attached is the Snapshot for reference.

Appreciate your help in advance

[image: Ventura]

PS: Same problem happens in Sonoma:

[image: Bandwidth consumption]

Answer (score 5):

`idleassetsd` has a short manpage entry:

> **idleassetsd** is used by the TVIdleServices framework for asset downloading and privileged operations. It is used by various clients in macOS. It is not meant to be invoked directly.

This indicates it's coming from tvOS and indeed used for downloading animated wallpapers.

Do you happen to have a shuffle collection selected in Wallpaper or Screen Saver in Settings? In this case, it seems that `idleassetsd` will download the wallpapers on-demand in the background as it's shuffling through them.

In my experience, `idleassetsd` will only download the actually selected wallpapers. I.e. if you select a not downloaded live wallpaper, it will start downloading, but if you then select another already downloaded wallpaper, the download will be stopped immediately.

If there's a specific WLAN or tethering connection you want prevent background downloads on, I suggest turning on "Low data mode" for that connection: In the Wi-Fi Settings, right-click the connected network, select "Network Settings…" and then toggle on "Low data mode" in the popup.

Answer (score 3):

I too had the problem, and my network used over 50 GB in a single day. When I saw the detailed report on the router, 97% were used by Apple.

I found this software called [Lulu](https://objective-see.org/products/lulu.html) and I blocked the process, and also applying the low data usage on the wifi settings also helped.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TVIdleServices.framework/idleassetsd
```

Answer (score -2):

it finally stopped after downloading about 43 GB of animated wallpapers

So the suggested solution is patience. wait until all wallpapers have been downloaded.

Answer (score -3):

I also experienced the same thing, this is very annoying, idleassetsd keeps downloading without stopping even though it's more than 20GB

the solution is downgrade to Ventura

Comment: Its occurring in Ventura too on my system.